# JxBrowser shows ssl errors when loading Google sites

Tags: java, ssl, javafx, jxbrowser

Good day guys. I'm using JxBrowser to display web pages, but it's giving me ssl errors when connecting to Google sites:

[image: SSL Google Error]

[image: SSL YouTube Error]

but it works for sites like wikipedia:

[image: Wikipedia]

Here is the code that's run on startup to load google.com in the new tab:

```
private void createNewTab(){
    Tab tempTab = new Tab();
    tempTab.setText("New Tab");
    AnchorPane tempAnchorPane = new AnchorPane();
    Browser tempBrowser = new Browser();
    BrowserView view = new BrowserView(tempBrowser);
    view.getBrowser().loadURL("https://google.com");        

    tempAnchorPane.getChildren().add(view);
    tempAnchorPane.setTopAnchor(view, 0.0);
    tempAnchorPane.setLeftAnchor(view, 0.0);
    tempAnchorPane.setRightAnchor(view, 0.0);
    tempAnchorPane.setBottomAnchor(view, 0.0);
    browserToTabMap.put(tempBrowser, tempTab);

    tempTab.setContent(view);
    rootPane.getTabs().add(tempTab);
}
```

as well as the code that calls that function on startup:

```
@FXML
void initialize() {
    assert rootPane != null : "fx:id=\"rootPane\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'Expedition.fxml'.";
    assert addressBar != null : "fx:id=\"addressBar\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'Expedition.fxml'.";




    BrowserView view = new BrowserView();
    root.addEventFilter(KeyEvent.KEY_TYPED, new EventHandler<KeyEvent>(){
        @Override
        public void handle(KeyEvent event) {
            if(processKeys(event)){
                System.out.println("Consuming event " + event);
                event.consume();
            }                    
        }
    });
    root.addEventFilter(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, new EventHandler<KeyEvent>(){
        @Override
        public void handle(KeyEvent event) {
            if(event.getCode() == KeyCode.ESCAPE){
                insertMode = false;
                System.out.println("Coming out of insert mode");
                rootPane.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().getContent().requestFocus();
                event.consume();
            }
        }            
    });

    addressBar.focusedProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>(){
        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> arg0, Boolean oldPropertyValue, Boolean newPropertyValue)
        {
            if (newPropertyValue)
            {
                System.out.println("addressBar focused");
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("addressBar out of focus");
                insertMode = false;
            }
        }
    });

    createNewTab();

    Runnable temp = () -> {
        try{
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        }
        catch(InterruptedException exc){

        }
        Platform.runLater(new Runnable(){
            @Override public void run(){
                ((Stage)rootPane.getScene().getWindow()).setMaximized(true);
                rootPane.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().getContent().requestFocus();
            }                
        });             
    };
    Thread tempThr = new Thread(temp);
    temp.run();
    currentTab = 0;
}
```

Here are the logs from the JxBrowser commandline output:

```
04:52:38 INFO: OS name: Linux
04:52:38 INFO: JRE version: 1.8.0_77 32-bit
04:52:38 INFO: JxBrowser version: 6.3
04:52:38 INFO: JxBrowser type: HEAVYWEIGHT
04:52:38 INFO: Starting IPC...
04:52:38 INFO: Starting IPC Server...
04:52:38 INFO: Starting socket server
04:52:38 INFO: Starting socket server at port 1101...
04:52:38 INFO: Starting IPC Process...
04:52:38 INFO: Starting Chromium process...
04:52:38 INFO: The '/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libudev.so.0' library exists: FALSE
04:52:38 INFO: The '/tmp/jxbrowser-chromium-43.0.2357.52.6.3/libudev.so.0' library exists: TRUE
04:52:38 INFO: The '/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcrypt.so.11' library exists: FALSE
04:52:38 INFO: The '/tmp/jxbrowser-chromium-43.0.2357.52.6.3/libgcrypt.so.11' library exists: TRUE
04:52:38 INFO: The '/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0' library exists: FALSE
04:52:38 INFO: The '/tmp/jxbrowser-chromium-43.0.2357.52.6.3/libcrypto.so.1.0.0' library exists: TRUE
04:52:38 INFO: Command line: /tmp/jxbrowser-chromium-43.0.2357.52.6.3/jxbrowser-chromium 1101 2069 
04:52:39 INFO: [0511/165239:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(172)] Running without the SUID sandbox! See https://code.google.com/p/chromium/wiki/LinuxSUIDSandboxDevelopment for more information on developing with the sandbox on.
04:52:39 INFO: Shared Memory Name: JXB1-2069
04:52:39 INFO: IPC connection has been established. Connection ID: 152876992
04:52:39 INFO: READ:  OnHelloMessage{type=OnHelloMessage, uid=1, message='cid:0,type:Main'}, null
04:52:39 INFO: Channel has been accepted: SocketChannel{cid=0, bid=-1, type=Main}
04:52:39 INFO: IPC is started.
04:52:39 INFO: WRITE: CreateBrowserMessage{type=CreateBrowser, uid=0, channelId=0, contextId=-1, cacheDir='/tmp/jxbrowser-chromium-43.0.2357.52.6.3/data/Cache', memoryDir='/tmp/jxbrowser-chromium-43.0.2357.52.6.3/data/Memory', dataDir='/tmp/jxbrowser-chromium-43.0.2357.52.6.3/data', currentLocale='en-us', proxyType=-1, proxyRules='null', proxyBypassRules='null', proxyAutoConfigURL='null', defaultZoomLevel=0.0, isOffScreenMode=false}, SocketInfo{cid=0, bid=-1, channelType=Main}
04:52:39 INFO: Shared Memory Name: JXB2-2069
04:52:39 INFO: IPC connection has been established. Connection ID: 149372272
04:52:39 INFO: [0511/165239:FATAL:scoped_file.cc(29)] Check failed: 0 == IGNORE_EINTR(close(fd)). : Bad file descriptor
04:52:39 INFO: READ:  OnHelloMessage{type=OnHelloMessage, uid=2, message='cid:0,bid:0,type:Browser'}, null
04:52:39 INFO: Channel has been accepted: SocketChannel{cid=0, bid=0, type=Browser}
04:52:39 INFO: Channel is connected: SocketChannel{cid=0, bid=0, type=Browser}
04:52:39 INFO: WRITE: SetNetworkDelegateConfigMessage{type=SetNetworkDelegateConfig, uid=1, browserContextId=-1, disableMessages=true}, SocketInfo{cid=0, bid=-1, channelType=Main}
04:52:39 INFO: WRITE: LoadURLMessage{type=LoadURL, uid=2, url='about:blank', frameId=-1, extraHeaders='null', postData=null}, SocketInfo{cid=0, bid=0, channelType=Browser}
04:52:40 INFO: READ:  com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.internal.ipc.message.OnRenderViewCreatedMessage@118143, SocketInfo{cid=0, bid=0, channelType=Browser}
04:52:40 INFO: [0511/165240:ERROR:renderer_main.cc(200)] Running without renderer sandbox
04:52:40 INFO: Shared Memory Name: JXB3-2069
04:52:40 INFO: IPC connection has been established. Connection ID: 149380056
04:52:40 INFO: READ:  OnHelloMessage{type=OnHelloMessage, uid=1, message='cid:0,bid:0,type:Render'}, null
04:52:40 INFO: Channel has been accepted: SocketChannel{cid=0, bid=0, type=Render}
04:52:40 INFO: Channel is connected: SocketChannel{cid=0, bid=0, type=Render}
04:52:40 INFO: READ:  OnHandleLoadMessage{type=OnHandleLoadMessage, uid=2, url='about:blank', loadType=5, loadPolicy=2, isBackForward=false, isRedirect=false, cancel=false}, SocketInfo{cid=0, bid=0, channelType=Render}
04:52:40 INFO: WRITE: OnHandleLoadMessage{type=OnHandleLoadMessage, uid=2, url='about:blank', loadType=5, loadPolicy=2, isBackForward=false, isRedirect=false, cancel=false}, SocketInfo{cid=0, bid=0, channelType=Render}
04:52:41 INFO: READ:  OnDidStartProvisionalLoadForFrameMessage{type=OnDidStartProvisionalLoadForFrame, uid=4, frameId=1, parentFrameId=-1, isMainFrame=true, validatedURL='about:blank', isErrorPage=false}, SocketInfo{cid=0, bid=0, channelType=Browser}
04:52:41 INFO: READ:  OnDidCommitProvisionalLoadForFrameMessage{type=OnDidCommitProvisionalLoadForFrame, uid=5, frameId=1, isMainFrame=true, transitionType=1, url='about:blank'}, SocketInfo{cid=0, bid=0, channelType=Browser}
04:52:41 INFO: READ:  OnStatusChangeMessage{type=OnStatusChangeMessage, uid=6, url=''}, SocketInfo{cid=0, bid=0, channelType=Browser}
04:52:41 INFO: READ:  OnDocumentLoadedInFrameMessage{type=OnDocumentLoadedInFrame, uid=7, frameId=1, isMainFrame=true}, SocketInfo{cid=0, bid=0, channelType=Browser}
04:52:41 INFO: READ:  OnDidFinishLoadMessage{type=OnDidFinishLoad, uid=8, frameId=1, isMainFrame=true, validatedURL='about:blank'}, SocketInfo{cid=0, bid=0, channelType=Browser}
04:52:41 INFO: JxBrowser type: HEAVYWEIGHT
04:52:41 INFO: Starting IPC...
04:52:41 INFO: IPC is already started.
04:52:41 INFO: WRITE: CreateBrowserMessage{type=CreateBrowser, uid=3, channelId=1, contextId=-1, cacheDir='/tmp/jxbrowser-chromium-43.0.2357.52.6.3/data/Cache', memoryDir='/tmp/jxbrowser-chromium-43.0.2357.52.6.3/data/Memory', dataDir='/tmp/jxbrowser-chromium-43.0.2357.52.6.3/data', currentLocale='en-us', proxyType=-1, proxyRules='null', proxyBypassRules='null', proxyAutoConfigURL='null', defaultZoomLevel=0.0, isOffScreenMode=false}, SocketInfo{cid=0, bid=-1, channelType=Main}
04:52:41 INFO: Shared Memory Name: JXB4-2069
04:52:41 INFO: IPC connection has been established. Connection ID: 152274456
04:52:41 INFO: READ:  OnHelloMessage{type=OnHelloMessage, uid=9, message='cid:1,bid:1,type:Browser'}, null
04:52:41 INFO: Channel has been accepted: SocketChannel{cid=1, bid=1, type=Browser}
04:52:41 INFO: Channel is connected: SocketChannel{cid=1, bid=1, type=Browser}
04:52:41 INFO: WRITE: SetNetworkDelegateConfigMessage{type=SetNetworkDelegateConfig, uid=4, browserContextId=-1, disableMessages=true}, SocketInfo{cid=0, bid=-1, channelType=Main}
04:52:41 INFO: WRITE: LoadURLMessage{type=LoadURL, uid=5, url='about:blank', frameId=-1, extraHeaders='null', postData=null}, SocketInfo{cid=1, bid=1, channelType=Browser}
04:52:41 INFO: READ:  com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.internal.ipc.message.OnRenderViewCreatedMessage@1c7f150, SocketInfo{cid=1, bid=1, channelType=Browser}
04:52:41 INFO: [0511/165241:ERROR:renderer_main.cc(200)] Running without renderer sandbox
04:52:41 INFO: Shared Memory Name: JXB5-2069
04:52:41 INFO: IPC connection has been established. Connection ID: 152275960
04:52:41 INFO: READ:  OnHelloMessage{type=OnHelloMessage, uid=1, message='cid:1,bid:1,type:Render'}, null
04:52:41 INFO: Channel has been accepted: SocketChannel{cid=1, bid=1, type=Render}
04:52:41 INFO: Channel is connected: SocketChannel{cid=1, bid=1, type=Render}
04:52:41 INFO: READ:  OnHandleLoadMessage{type=OnHandleLoadMessage, uid=2, url='about:blank', loadType=5, loadPolicy=2, isBackForward=false, isRedirect=false, cancel=false}, SocketInfo{cid=1, bid=1, channelType=Render}
04:52:41 INFO: WRITE: OnHandleLoadMessage{type=OnHandleLoadMessage, uid=2, url='about:blank', loadType=5, loadPolicy=2, isBackForward=false, isRedirect=false, cancel=false}, SocketInfo{cid=1, bid=1, channelType=Render}
04:52:41 INFO: READ:  OnDidStartProvisionalLoadForFrameMessage{type=OnDidStartProvisionalLoadForFrame, uid=11, frameId=1, parentFrameId=-1, isMainFrame=true, validatedURL='about:blank', isErrorPage=false}, SocketInfo{cid=1, bid=1, channelType=Browser}
04:52:41 INFO: READ:  OnDidCommitProvisionalLoadForFrameMessage{type=OnDidCommitProvisionalLoadForFrame, uid=12, frameId=1, isMainFrame=true, transitionType=1, url='about:blank'}, SocketInfo{cid=1, bid=1, channelType=Browser}
04:52:41 INFO: READ:  OnStatusChangeMessage{type=OnStatusChangeMessage, uid=13, url=''}, SocketInfo{cid=1, bid=1, channelType=Browser}
04:52:41 INFO: READ:  OnDocumentLoadedInFrameMessage{type=OnDocumentLoadedInFrame, uid=14, frameId=1, isMainFrame=true}, SocketInfo{cid=1, bid=1, channelType=Browser}
04:52:41 INFO: READ:  OnDidFinishLoadMessage{type=OnDidFinishLoad, uid=15, frameId=1, isMainFrame=true, validatedURL='about:blank'}, SocketInfo{cid=1, bid=1, channelType=Browser}
04:52:41 INFO: WRITE: LoadURLMessage{type=LoadURL, uid=6, url='https://google.com', frameId=-1, extraHeaders='null', postData=null}, SocketInfo{cid=1, bid=1, channelType=Browser}
04:52:41 INFO: READ:  OnHandleLoadMessage{type=OnHandleLoadMessage, uid=3, url='https://google.com/', loadType=5, loadPolicy=2, isBackForward=false, isRedirect=false, cancel=false}, SocketInfo{cid=1, bid=1, channelType=Render}
04:52:41 INFO: WRITE: OnHandleLoadMessage{type=OnHandleLoadMessage, uid=3, url='https://google.com/', loadType=5, loadPolicy=2, isBackForward=false, isRedirect=false, cancel=false}, SocketInfo{cid=1, bid=1, channelType=Render}
04:52:41 INFO: READ:  OnDidStartProvisionalLoadForFrameMessage{type=OnDidStartProvisionalLoadForFrame, uid=16, frameId=1, parentFrameId=-1, isMainFrame=true, validatedURL='https://google.com/', isErrorPage=false}, SocketInfo{cid=1, bid=1, channelType=Browser}
04:52:41 INFO: READ:  OnShouldBeginRequestMessage{type=OnShouldBeginRequest, uid=17, browserContextId=-1, url='https://google.com/', method='GET', resourceType=0, cancel=false}, SocketInfo{cid=0, bid=-1, channelType=Main}
04:52:41 INFO: WRITE: OnShouldBeginRequestMessage{type=OnShouldBeginRequest, uid=17, browserContextId=-1, url='https://google.com/', method='GET', resourceType=0, cancel=false}, SocketInfo{cid=0, bid=-1, channelType=Main}
04:52:41 INFO: READ:  OnCanGetCookiesMessage{type=OnCanGetCookies, uid=18, url='https://google.com/', cookies='', browserContextId=-1, canGetCookies=true}, SocketInfo{cid=0, bid=-1, channelType=Main}
04:52:41 INFO: WRITE: OnCanGetCookiesMessage{type=OnCanGetCookies, uid=18, url='https://google.com/', cookies='', browserContextId=-1, canGetCookies=true}, SocketInfo{cid=0, bid=-1, channelType=Main}
04:52:43 INFO: [0511/165243:WARNING:nss_ssl_util.cc(370)] Unknown SSL error -12218 (SSL_ERROR_ENCRYPTION_FAILURE) mapped to net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR
04:52:45 INFO: READ:  OnDidFailProvisionalLoadMessage{type=OnDidFailProvisionalLoad, uid=19, frameId=1, isMainFrame=true, validatedURL='https://google.com/', errorCode=-107, errorDescription='SSL protocol error.'}, SocketInfo{cid=1, bid=1, channelType=Browser}
04:52:45 INFO: READ:  OnDidStartProvisionalLoadForFrameMessage{type=OnDidStartProvisionalLoadForFrame, uid=20, frameId=1, parentFrameId=-1, isMainFrame=true, validatedURL='data:text/html,chromewebdata', isErrorPage=true}, SocketInfo{cid=1, bid=1, channelType=Browser}
04:52:45 INFO: READ:  OnDidCommitProvisionalLoadForFrameMessage{type=OnDidCommitProvisionalLoadForFrame, uid=21, frameId=1, isMainFrame=true, transitionType=1, url='https://google.com/'}, SocketInfo{cid=1, bid=1, channelType=Browser}
04:52:45 INFO: READ:  OnStatusChangeMessage{type=OnStatusChangeMessage, uid=22, url=''}, SocketInfo{cid=1, bid=1, channelType=Browser}
04:52:45 INFO: READ:  OnDocumentAvailableInMainFrameMessage{type=OnDocumentAvailableInMainFrame, uid=23}, SocketInfo{cid=1, bid=1, channelType=Browser}
04:52:45 INFO: READ:  OnDidCreateScriptContextMessage{type=OnDidCreateScriptContext, uid=4, frameId=-1, contextPtr=149308800}, SocketInfo{cid=1, bid=1, channelType=Render}
04:52:45 INFO: WRITE: OnDidCreateScriptContextMessage{type=OnDidCreateScriptContext, uid=4, frameId=-1, contextPtr=149308800}, SocketInfo{cid=1, bid=1, channelType=Render}
04:52:45 INFO: READ:  OnTitleChangeMessage{type=OnTitleChange, uid=24, title='https://google.com/ failed to load'}, SocketInfo{cid=1, bid=1, channelType=Browser}
04:52:45 INFO: READ:  OnDocumentLoadedInFrameMessage{type=OnDocumentLoadedInFrame, uid=25, frameId=1, isMainFrame=true}, SocketInfo{cid=1, bid=1, channelType=Browser}
04:52:46 INFO: READ:  OnDidFinishLoadMessage{type=OnDidFinishLoad, uid=26, frameId=1, isMainFrame=true, validatedURL='data:text/html,chromewebdata'}, SocketInfo{cid=1, bid=1, channelType=Browser}
04:52:48 INFO: WRITE: FrameMovedMessage{type=FrameMoved, uid=7, x=13, y=113, width=1000, height=937}, SocketInfo{cid=1, bid=1, channelType=Browser}
04:52:48 INFO: WRITE: FrameSetBoundsMessage{type=FrameSetBounds, uid=8, x=0, y=62, width=1000, height=937}, SocketInfo{cid=1, bid=1, channelType=Browser}
04:52:48 INFO: WRITE: FrameMovedMessage{type=FrameMoved, uid=9, x=13, y=113, width=1000, height=937}, SocketInfo{cid=1, bid=1, channelType=Browser}
04:52:48 INFO: WRITE: FrameFocusMessage{type=FrameFocus, uid=10, focus=false}, SocketInfo{cid=1, bid=1, channelType=Browser}
04:52:48 INFO: WRITE: FrameAttachMessage{type=FrameAttach, uid=11, windowHandle=62914563}, SocketInfo{cid=1, bid=1, channelType=Browser}
04:52:48 INFO: WRITE: SetDragDropEnabledMessage{type=SetDragDropEnabled, uid=12, enabled='true'}, SocketInfo{cid=1, bid=1, channelType=Browser}
04:52:48 INFO: WRITE: FrameSetBoundsMessage{type=FrameSetBounds, uid=13, x=0, y=63, width=1000, height=937}, SocketInfo{cid=1, bid=1, channelType=Browser}
04:52:48 INFO: WRITE: FrameMovedMessage{type=FrameMoved, uid=14, x=0, y=114, width=1024, height=630}, SocketInfo{cid=1, bid=1, channelType=Browser}
04:52:48 INFO: WRITE: FrameSetBoundsMessage{type=FrameSetBounds, uid=15, x=0, y=63, width=1024, height=630}, SocketInfo{cid=1, bid=1, channelType=Browser}
04:52:48 INFO: WRITE: FrameMovedMessage{type=FrameMoved, uid=16, x=0, y=114, width=1024, height=630}, SocketInfo{cid=1, bid=1, channelType=Browser}
```

Answer (score 1):

JxBrowser 6.3 is based on Chromium 43. As far as I know Chromium 43 has several issues with updated NSS library on latest Linux distributions such as Ubuntu 15.10. According to the bug report at https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/chromium-browser/+bug/1547762 Chromium versions less than 48 has incompatibility issues with latest Ubuntu security updates that break HTTPS functionality in Chromium engine. In Chromium 48 and higher the issue isn't reproducible.

We have prepared updated build of [JxBrowser 6.4](http://cloud.teamdev.com/downloads/jxbrowser/jxbrowser-6.4-cross-desktop-win_mac_linux.zip) based on Chromium 49. Could you please try it in your Linux environment and let me know if it helps.